# Connecting to MongoDB using Express

Tags: html, mongodb, express

I am having trouble understanding what needs to be done in order to connect to MongoDB so i can insert an Object into the database.  I am new to using Express as well as MongoDB and don't have a full grasp on the both of them yet.

My app.js which was created using the standard Express setup is as follows.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ex_session = require('express-session');
var dateformat = require('dateformat');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/contacts'

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

My index.js is as follows and what i would like to happen is when a post request is made from /mailer, a connection is made to the MongoDB in order to set up for an insert.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/contacts';
var contacts;

/* GET home page. */
var start = function(req, res, next){
  console.log("Starting!");
  res.render('mailer',{});
}

router.get('/', start);
router.get('/mailer', start);

/* Post mailer Page insert into database*/
 router.post('/mailer', function(req, res, next){
   res.render('thanks');
   console.log("Welcome to the Thank You Page");

   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
     if(err == NULL){
       console.log("Connected to database");

       // parse the body of the page and set up object to send to the                
       // database  

    }
   });

   });



 router.get('/contact', function(req, res){
   res.render('contact', {});
 })

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Typically, you don't want to create a new mongo connection every time you want to query / insert, though for sake of simplicity it is alright. Other than that you seem to be on the right track, and I'm having difficulty understanding what it is exactly that you need help with.

Comment: I get an error every time i try to connect to the database saying Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.  How would i set it up so it only connects once instead of everytime i set up a post.

Comment: This is really basic stuff, which is very hard to explain in a short StackOverflow comment or answer. There are lots of tutorials about this though, it should be pretty easy to find a few examples on how it's usually done.

Comment: @svens “If you can't explain it to a six year old, you don't understand it yourself.”

Comment: @CharlieMartin Read again. It's not that hard to explain, it's just a lot of (too much for me) effort to start from zero in a StackOverflow post. This was just good advice for the OP, in case he doesn't get good answers here. Also there are multiple issues in his code, which is again not very well suited for SO questions. I think the current answers are enough proof for that. OP would be much better helped by either asking in a chat room or as I suggested work through a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

*for express ,

```
 var mongo = require('mongodb');
        var MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;    
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://'+DB_USERNAME+':'+DB_PASSWORD+'@'+DB_HOST+':'DB_PORT+'/'+DB_NAME,function(err, db){  
              if(err) 
                console.log(err);
              else
              {
                console.log('Mongo Conn....');

              }
            });
```

//for local server for express
//in local server DBPASSWOAD and DBusername not required

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://'+DB_HOST+':'+DB_PORT+'/'+DB_NAME,function(err, db){  
      if(err) 
        console.log(err);
      else
      {
        console.log('Mongo Conn....');

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is super mess，I can show your my configuration and u can refer to.

```
db.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export default function connectDB() {
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contacts');
    mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
        console.log('mongodb connected.');
    });
};


app.js
import connectDB from "db.js";

connectDB();


user.model.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    mobile: {type: String},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', schema, 'user');

export default User;
```

then in your router file u can call User.find() or User.update or ...

Comment: It really isn't that messy and this won't solve his issue, which has more to do with express middleware order than Mongo

Comment: I dont quite undertand what the mean of "has more to do with express middleware order than Mongo", but “MongoClient.connect” in the router function apparently it not a good coding habit.

Comment: OP says he is getting "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." which means he is sending two responses to one request